# Bulk files rename

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have 10000 files (php, html, css, and png). They are interconnected, in other words that the site engine. How do I can to do a bulk rename files so that the website worked properly? I understand that in addition to rename files and folders, I need to rename the paths inside the files. But how to do it bulk?

Comment: Can you give an example of what needs to be renamed? Also, you've tagged this as `javascript` and `php` — do you need a way to rename files programmatically? Or is this a one-time operation? If it is, what type of access do you have to these files (e.g., can you SSH to the server and run commands directly)?

Comment: Need a lot more specifics if you want help

Comment: I have all the files are on my computer. I need a script or some program which can do it. In other words, I need to rename all 10,000 files, and that after the rename the site to work properly.  I need to do this only 1 time

Comment: So you need someone to write a script for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what value renaming the **files** would be...the paths might be more applicable here. But - http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

Comment: This can be done with "refactoring" functions of some IDE's like PHPStorm.

When using refactoring functionalities, they make sure that all the places where the file is being called will have it renamed. However, to void problems, this should be done by somebody who knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution can be to write a little custom program. That program can do what you want. It may be a php script.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand this) Maybe there is already ready decision?